# Report times out in Report Builder but works fine in Management Studio

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a simple report that I have built in Management Studio and it returns results in under a minute but when I transfer the same query over to Report Builder and try to run it, the report times out. I have other, very similar reports on that same server that run just fine. I guess my question is what is the difference between running a report in Management Studio and running that same report in Report Builder?

Comment: What product is this?   SQL is a query language, not an application.

Comment: I feel like I spelled that out pretty clearly in the subject and in the body of the question...?